# Suggest rename of [ink] to [rust-ink]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Tag [ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ink) was re-created a year ago.

I happened to get into the subject of ambiguous [ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ink) tag [years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215903/ambiguous-ink-tag) and would recommend rename of tag.

Comment: [substrate-ink] may also have potential, since its a tool exclusive to the Substrate network (I believe).

Comment: Maybe the ink tag should be [blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295149/232762) after the current one has been renamed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need a mod for this since there are only a few questions.

I've retagged them as [rust-ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-ink). The [ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ink) tag will get deleted by the roomba later since there are no remaining open questions.

Comment: You missed one :D

Comment: @Braiam Someone can correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think the roomba pays attention to closed questions, so I left it deliberately. I'm not sure what happens in that case, whether the tag is simply removed (leaving a question that's potentially got 0 tags -- not usually possible), or whether the question gets deleted too. I think there might be undesirable consequences to editing closed questions too: either that they get bumped, or entered into a review queue or something. Sorry I'm hazy on the specifics and couldn't find much info about it by searching.

Comment: Roomba is just the autodelete from Community, they are all just scripts. The tag system looks at all visible questions to decide if it's a "new tag" or it's not.

Comment: @Braiam I know its a script. I believe it's a script that removes a tag provided it's not on any *open* questions.

Comment: @Michael tag only edits don't bump questions neither put it in review queues, at least that's what someone told me once I asked this in chat.

Comment: @Magnetron any edit "bump" the question in the active tab. If it's a suggested edit, it is put in the suggested edit queue.

Comment: I added a synonym for good measure